# How to state formally that we are using the Division Algorithm

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing, terminology

In elementary number theory, there is a result that states the following.

> The remainder of the division of any integer squared by $4$ is $0$ or $1$.

This is a result with a quite simple proof but my thought is not on the proof itself. My doubt is on the use of mathematically correct terms to express some ideas that may appear trivial or intuitive.

To prove this proposition, one may start by picking up an arbitrary integer, say $n$. By the Division Algorithm, we know that $\color{blue}{\textrm{we can divide $n$ by $2$}}$ and we get unique integer $q$ and $r$ such that $n = 2q+r$ and $0 \leq r < 2$. From this, we know that $\color{blue}{\textrm{each integer can be written in the form $n=2k$ or $n=2j+1$}}$, for some integers $k,j$.

If $n=2k$, then $n^2=(2k)^2=4k^2$. By letting $q’ = k^2$, we can write $n^2 = 4q’ + 0$. Since $q’$ and $0$ are integers and $0 \leq 0 < 4$, we get that an integer of the form $n=2k$ $\color{blue}{\textrm{leaves remainder $0$ under the division by $4$}}$.

Now, if $n=2j+1$, then $n^2=(2j+1)^2=4(j^2+j)+1$. By letting $q’’ = j^2+j$, we can write $n^2 = 4q’’ + 1$. Since $q’’$ and $1$ are integers and $0 \leq 1 < 4$, we get that an integer of the form $n=2j+1$ $\color{blue}{\textrm{leaves remainder $1$ under the division by $4$}}$.

Therefore, the remainder of the division of any integer squared by $4$ is $0$ or $1$ and this ends or proof.

**But** can one say also the following, without loss of rigor?

> If $n = 2k$ for some integer $k$, then $n^2 = 4q’$ for $q’ = k^2 \in \Bbb{Z}$. If $n = 2j+1$ for some integer $j$, then $n^2 = 4q’’+1$ for $q’’ = j^2+j \in \Bbb{Z}$. So, the square of any integer $n$ is of the form $4p$ or $4p+1$ for some $p \in \Bbb{Z}$. Since, $0 \leq 0,1 < 4$, we conclude by the Algorithm Division that the remainder of the division of any integer squared by $4$ is $0$ or $1$.

**IN SHORT**

$*$ What is the most formally correct approach to this proof between these two? Please, feel free to suggest your owns. Thank you.

Comment: They look essentially the same to me except that the first gives a reason for all integers being either double another integer or one more than double another integer.  I already knew that, so do not need that step to convince me

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @Henry . I just wrote that step to illustrate the type of statements that I was wondering if they were formally correct

Comment: You haven't given the details of "we conclude by the Algorithm..." Is it not the same as in the first proof? It is impossible to answer your question without those details.